# In Botframework Webchat how do I customize color when hovering Adaptive Card actions and send button

Tags: css, botframework

By overruling the defaultStyleOptions.js of the BotFramework webchat client, I am customizing the client. THis works fine for one part. I am not able to modify the focus color when hovering over Adaptive Card actions or hovering the send button (see attached picture) I tried overruling different properties that made sense but without succes. Help appreciated.

I tried modifying the following properties:
default accent and default subtle
cardEmphasisBackgroundColor
sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus
sendBoxButtonColorOnHover

```
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it@8.4.2/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it-emoji/1.4.0/markdown-it-emoji.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>   
    <script>
      // make sure the chat initializes at page load by sending a 'webchat join' event
       const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
         if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
           dispatch({
             type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
             payload: {
               name: 'webchat/join',
               value: { language: window.navigator.language }
             }
           });
         }
         return next(action);
       });
       // add markdown support including Emoji
        var markdownIt = window.markdownit();
        markdownIt = window.markdownit().use(window.markdownitEmoji);
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: webChatToken}),
        renderMarkdown: markdownIt.render.bind(markdownIt),
        store,
        // styling
        styleOptions: {

        rootHeight: '755px',
        rootWidth: 'Auto',
        backgroundColor: 'White',
        bubbleBorder: 'solid 1px Light Blue',
        bubbleTextColor: '#0D0D0D',

        avatarSize: 50,
        botAvatarImage: 'https://botz4u.com/src/assets/img/png/botz4uavatar.png',
        botAvatarInitials: 'BOT',


        userAvatarInitials: 'JIJ',
        bubbleFromUserBorder: 'solid 1px Light Blue',
        bubbleFromUserTextColor: '#0D0D0D',

        hideUploadButton: true,
        sendBoxBorderTop: 'solid 1px #0A9BFB',
        sendBoxBorderBottom: 'solid 1px #0A9BFB',
        },
        userID: 'N/A',
        username: 'Web Chat User',
        locale: 'nl-NL'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The adaptive card definition used in the caption:

```
 "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "spacing": "none",
                    "size": "medium",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Welkom!"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Image",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                    "url": "<link to logo>",
                    "size": "Stretch" 
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "spacing": "medium",
                    "size": "medium",
                    "color": "Dark",
                    "text": "some text"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "some text",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Wat is een chatbot?",
            "data": "Wat is een chatbot"
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Waarom een chatbot?",
            "data": "Waarom een chatbot"
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Wat kost een chatbot?",
            "data": "Wat kost het"
        }
    ],

    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
```

and the bot-code showing the adaptive card to the user (in the caption it is the introcard:

```
    if (qnaResults[0] && qnaResults[0].score > 0.5) {
                if (qnaResults[0].answer === '#Weather') {
                    var weerVoorspelling = await helper.getWeatherForecast(turnContext);
                    await turnContext.sendActivity('Als je bedoelt dat je een weerbericht wilt, bij deze ....');
                    await turnContext.sendActivity({
                        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(weerVoorspelling)]
                    });
                } else if (qnaResults[0].answer === '#DateTime') {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity(moment().tz('Europe/Amsterdam').format('[Vandaag is het ]LL[ en de tijd is ] LT[ uur.]'));
                } else if (qnaResults[0].answer === '#Help') {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity({
                        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(IntroCard)]
                    });
                } else {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);
                }
            // If QnaMaker did not find an answer, offer help
            }
```

I would expect to be able to modify the colors mentioned above.[image: Picture showing the parts of the webchat I need to customize]

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve: when I use the value `sendBoxButtonColorOnHover`, which you mentioned is not working, I successfully got the color variable that I put when I navigate with my mouse over the button logo

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. That one works for the button indeed. What I would like to change is the square surrounding the button that appears when I hover the button. I don't have a clue what that is.

Comment: Ok. And for what you called Suggested actions, are you sure it is suggested actions? Looks like prompt options on your capture

Comment: You are right of course. Actually actions from an adaptive card translated into prompt option (I guess). Should have been more precise.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your bot code which generate these items?

Comment: With pleasure. I added the samples above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General - Using variables to set style

You can have a look to the available variables in the Webchat sources, in particular [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js).

### Regarding your question

For the *sendButton*, you can also see the `SendBoxButton.js` file [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/StyleSet/SendBoxButton.js):

- the value `sendBoxButtonColorOnHover` is working well in order to set the color of the SVG on hover
- there is currently no parameter for changing the background color (of the div containing the svg) on hover

For your *Adaptive Cards buttons*, source is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/bundle/src/adaptiveCards/Styles/StyleSet/AdaptiveCardRenderer.js). As you can see, it is not using `hover` currently.

### General - How to add custom styling not currently supported:

Regarding needs of custom styling, you should have a look to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.a.branding-webchat-styling#why-stylesetoptions) page on Github talking about how you should handle fields that are not available in `defaultStyleOptions`.

In a few words:

- Create a Pull Request for your new fields, they will take them into account with pleasure
- The worst solution (as it is not officially supported and may be subject to breaking changes later) is to do some "Idiosyncratic manual styling", see sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/05.b.idiosyncratic-manual-styling/README.md)